# DD remote disk from windows

Tags: ssh, dd, remote

I am trying to image a disk for one of our network appliances and am running into an issue with saving the output file.

This is the command:

```
ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell "dd if=/dev/md0 |gzip -1 -" dd of=md0_monSecondary.gz"
```

The screen outputs a bunch of garbled text and at the end says the following:

```
Lgzip: can't stat: dd: No such file or directory
gzip: can't stat: of=md0_blah.gz: No such file or directory
```

The other command we were given is this:

```
ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell "dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > md0.img"
```

If I run that I get a Error:

```
No such command
```

If I run it without quotes

```
ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > md0.img
```

I get a message that says:

```
'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong with these commands?

Comment: If I run the ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > md0.img from another networking appliance, I get the following:  stdout:: command not found

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dd` with a compressed stream but without `iblock=fullblock` you are likely to end up with a corrupted image. It's much easier just to use `cat` (or in this case, `gzip`) and dispense with the complexities of `dd` entirely:

```
ssh -n blah@192.0.0.0 shell 'gzip </dev/md0' >md0_monSecondary.gz
```

If the server on 192.0.0.0 really cannot handle `gzip` directly from a device, for example if it's based on BSD rather than Linux, then use this. But only use this variant as a last resort:

```
ssh -n blah@192.0.0.0 shell 'dd bs=128M if=/dev/md0 | gzip' >md0_monSecondary.gz
```

The `shell` component of the command line is very unusual. I assume it's something related to the type of server you're using. For a normal server you wouldn't need it at all.

Bear in mind that if `/dev/md0` is still mounted as a filesystem on the remote server while you're copying it the resulting image is highly likely to be corrupted. If you're lucky you'll notice straightaway. If you're not, then the potential corruption will sit there until you need the image restored.

Comment: TY!  The device's OS is based on freebsd.  That is why the need for the shell.  I got this working on a coworker's linux box.  

ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > 192.0.0.0_md0.img  Does this prevent corruption?  Are disks like this prone to corruption?
/dev/raid/r0s1a 
/dev/raid/r0s1e

Comment: If I run this from my windows VM:ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > 192.0.0.0_md0.img, I get a "'tail' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." error.  Is that just not supported?  How do we specify the path to the img file in Windows?

ssh blah@192.0.0.0 shell dd if=/dev/md0 bs=10M | tail -c +7 | head -c -6 > C:\temp\192.0.0.0_md0.img

Comment: Why are you running `tail` at all?

Comment: @JohnBalan note that without any quoting, anything after `|` is executed on the client host. (I suppose it really depends on your client shell but practically it's probably the case anyway.)